# Need help creating a receipt using a user inputted list

Tags: python

I am having trouble when I end the program it displays -1 as the price instead of adding all of the inputs from the user.

I have been trying to create a receipt using a list with the code in this format:

```
prices=[]

while(True):

p = float(input("Enter a price: " ))

prices.append(p)

for i in range(len(prices)):

print( prices[i] )
```

With these instructions:

1. On Receipt, you show all prices entered.

   a. Save all prices to a list.
   b. Re-enter price if negative numbers are entered
2. Display all elements in a list with for loop.
3. Use list sum() to get subtotal, calculate tax, total, and display these values.
4. Show a dollar sign for each amount (import locale).

This is my code so far:

```
subtotal= 0
tax= 0
total= 0

prices =[]
count=0
while(True):
    p = float(input("Enter a price: " ))

    if(p >= 0):
        count += 1
        continue

    elif(p == -1):

        break

prices.append(p)

sum(prices)
subtotal = sum(prices)
tax = subtotal * 0.06
total = subtotal + tax

for index, item in enumerate(prices, 1):
    print(f"Item {index}                    ${item}")

for i in range(len(prices)):
    print( prices[i] )
```

This is what I want the end product to look like:

```
Item 1 *******************************($ 1st price entered)
Item 2 *******************************($ 2nd price entered)
Item 3 *******************************($ 3rd price entered)
Item 4 *******************************($ 4th price entered)
```

(* replaced with blank spaces)

continues with however many inputs the user made

```
Tax ***********************************($ sum of tax with 0.06 * subtotal)
Subtotal *****************************($ every input from the user added up)
Total *********************************($ subtotal and tax added together)
```

Comment: The code display item 1 as -1 instead of ignoring the -1 and adding up all of the other inputs.

Comment: `prices.append(p)` should be in the `if p > 0:` block. Your code appends the last value of `p`, which is always `-1` because that's how you get out of the loop.

Comment: Your first comment should be in the question, not a comment.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry about that, this was my first question I just didn't think about it until after asking. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's why there's an "Edit" button.